# Storing array in db using serialize but get offset error when unserializing it back in php.

Tags: php, mysql, facebook-graph-api, serialization, multidimensional-array

I have an array of friend id's and I am trying to store this list in a db per user.

```
$share_friend_id = ( serialize($share_id_array));
```

My db looks like this:
1510161011146851    John    a:2:{i:0;s:8:"Kabo Lee";i:1;s:6:"Bo Lee";}  a:2:{i:0;s:15:"601599471189716";i:1;s:16:"15327449...

The first column is the user id, then name, then the list of friend id's that has been converted from an array to a string using serialize function.

I am trying to get this data back in php. I have the following:

```
     while ($row = $friendresult->fetch_assoc()) {
     //for friend(s)
    $id[] = $row['friend_id'];
    $name = $row['friend_name'];
    $friend_share_friend_id  = ($row['share_friend_id']);
    }

$data = array();    
$data = ( unserialize($friend_share_friend_id));
print_r($data);
```

But I get the error: Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 61 of 60 bytes in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\sql.php

I am not sure if it is a good idea to use serialize function. Anyone got any suggestions or advice?

Comment: Is this database call expected to return multiple rows, or just one?

Comment: @fondillusions could you try to print $friend_share_friend_id using var_dump(); and show us the results

Comment: Instead of serialize could you use json_encode / json_decode functions?

Comment: @MohammadAlabed It did work before but then now I am getting the error offset. I did var_dump and this is what I get: string(60) "a:2:{i:0;s:15:"601599473289716";i:1;s:16:"1532744956945336";"

Comment: @user574632 - it is expected to return multiple rows of different user ids... I am trying to get their list of friend ids.

Comment: @fondillusions then you have a problem, in that `$friend_share_friend_id` and `$name` will get overwritten in each itteration of the while loop. Also the aditional brackets you put around some assignments is confusing:`$share_friend_id = ( serialize($share_id_array));` should be `$share_friend_id = serialize($share_id_array);` This wont cause an error, but its hard to read

Comment: Hi @jeff. Instead of serialize, do you think i could just implode and explode? Kinda confused with json_encode/decode....

Answer (score 0):

try next

```
<?php
$share_friend_id = ( serialize($share_id_array));
$share_friend_id_2  = unserialize($share_friend_id);
var_dump($share_friend_id_2);  
?>
```

if it is working without any problem that means the field in DB doesn't have enough space to store all data string

Comment: I'm new with creating a database. That might be in. I have varchar string - length 60 :S probably not big enough. How big can I allocate it? Does it matter if I allocate with a large length even if I don't need or?

Comment: I have just changed it to 600 but I still get the error.

Comment: try to make type as TEXT not varchar

Comment: Even if the values are numbers?

Comment: yes of course because the serialize returns string,, just try to see if the problem from size or not